# should i send verification link to his old email account when he want to change email address of his account?

Tags: logic

when a user want to change his account email address, should i send verification link to his old email account?

I should beacuse worry hacker change her email address after success hacked.

I should not because the reason he want to change is email address is because he cannot login his old email account.

Any solution for this conflict? Should or should not?

Comment: This is off-topic (it's not really a programming question).  But a simple solution: send it to both.  If it was a hacker, the real user will now be alerted to the fact.

Comment: if i send it to both, this also cannot prevent hacker change her email address.

The hacker cannot change his login password because need verification link from the user old email account, so i cannot let the hacker change the email address, otherwise he will able to change the password.

Comment: If an account has been hacked, then the best you can hope for is to alert the real user, so that they can contact you.

Comment: New account = verification link and old account = message of changing email address.

Comment: @Sb Sangpi, Great idea, and save old email address as reference number, so that the real owner can prove that he is the real owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable question but in this situation you can sent **Verification link to New account**  and **Sent the information about changing email address to the old account**.

Comment: what if the hacker hack the user's old email account. And the real user create new email account. Both of them (real user and hacker) report to me and ask me ban the email address. How can I verify which 1 is the real user and which 1 is the hacker?

Answer (score 0):

Your worries are right, additionally the old email account may be unaccessable because of other reasons like forgotten password etc. So it is not a good idea to sent verification to old email address. But to send verification email to new address the user should have identified himself by password or whatever verification is used.

Comment: the hacker already know the account password, that's why he able to login and try to change the password and email address.